# Limit $I=\lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\int_0 ^1 x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)d x}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Im a new participant in this mathematical forum, so this is one of that i couldn't solve it.

$$I=\lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\int_0 ^1 x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)d x}$$

I've tried to transform the product in a summation as function of a logarithmic function, and I wasn't been successful. Like $u=x^n$, $du=nx^{n-1}dx$

$g_n(u) = \sqrt[n]{\frac{ dx}{du} \cdot x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^n(1 - x^k)}$

$g_n(u)=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{nx^{n-1}}} \cdot x^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(1 - x^k)}$

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123621/how-to-compute-this-limit/1124080?sfb=2#1124080 for related techniques.

Comment: They are not exactly the same. The power of $x$ inside the integral differs.

Comment: Yes. By the way, since $x^k-x^{2k}$ is $\leq \frac{1}{4}$ on $[0,1]$, the limit here is $\leq\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Is this from a particular contest?

Answer (score 3):

See if this converts to a Riemann sum which converges to an integral:
$$g_n(u)=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{nx^{n-1}}} \cdot x^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(1 - x^k)}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{nx^{1-1/n}}} \cdot u^{\frac{n+1}{2n}} \cdot e^{\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(1 - x^k)}\\\sim \sqrt{u}\exp\int_0^1\ln(1-u^t)dt=\sqrt u\exp\frac{\zeta(2)-{\rm Li}_2(u)}{\ln u}$$
The maxima seems to be $\approx0.185155$ at $u\approx 0.245254$ without possibly a closed form as [wolfram says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+sqrt%28u%29+exp%28%28pi%5E2%2F6-Li_2%28u%29%29%2Flog%28u%29%29).

Comment: (+1) I agree. The limit is the value of $$\sqrt{u}\exp\frac{\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(u)}{\log u}$$ in the first positive root of $$\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(u) = \frac{1}{2}\log^2 u+\log u \log(1-u), $$ hence $u(1-u)$ for $u\approx 0.245254$.

Answer (score 1):

As $$\sqrt{x^k(1-x^k)}\le\frac{x^k+(1-x^k)}2=\frac12\iff x^k(1-x^k)\le\frac14$$
So:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\int_0 ^1 x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)d x}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\int_0 ^1 \prod_{k=1}^nx^k(1-x^k)}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1\left(\frac14\right)^ndx}=\frac14$$
So the limit is $\displaystyle\le\frac14$
Note that equality holds here not for a definite values but $\sqrt[k]2$ which are all less than $0.5$

Comment: I got it, nice one ! Thanks +1

Comment: @Vinisth no 1/4 is not the answer. I mean the answer is less than 1/4

Comment: Yes i got it, it can simplify the problem