# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0 ^1(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)d x$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0 ^1(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)d x.$$

I tried to use the Beta function to calculate this limit, and I failed because I didn’t know how to calculate the gamma function like “gamma(1/n)”.

Similar method: [how to compute this limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123621/how-to-compute-this-limit/1124080?sfb=2#1124080)

I don’t know if it converges. But if it converges, I guess the limit is the 1/e. Because I try to use desmos to calculate the limited term and get a result like 1/e.

[desmos pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrKDJ.jpg)

Comment: This? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883140/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019758/42969

Comment: According to the linked threads, the integral is $\frac{4\pi\sqrt3}{\sqrt{23}}\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi\sqrt{23}}3}{\cosh\frac{\pi\sqrt{23}}2} \approx 0.3684125359314337$, which is close, but not equal, to $1/e \approx 0.36787944117144233$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you Martin R, maybe I use different form and didn’t find the same problem.